# What is the right question?I played football at the weekend 1-Where did you play? 2-where did you played?

Tags: grammar

I played football at the weekend

> 1-Where did you **play**?
>
> 2-where did you **played**?

Comment: This isn't what you were asking about, but also you would say "I played football on the weekend" or "over the weekend" not "at the weekend".

Answer (score 2):

The first option: **Where did you play?** Is the correct one.

When forming the past tense in questions, we use an auxiliary verb "do" to indicate tense. So do becomes did.  The main verb has the bare infinitive form, and never changes.

> Where did you play?
>
> Where do you play?
>
> Where does he play?

If another auxillary verb is used (for example for perfect tense or continuous tense) that changes, not the main verb

> Where is he playing?
>
> Where was he playing?

Comment: I've made a big edit.  When you answer a question don't just state "this one is right". That doesn't explain your answer. Instead try to explain why one answer is right and the other is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a question about forming questions about the past, specifically the interrogative equivalent of the past simple. You want, I gather, the question that might lead to the answer "I played at Footown Stadium".

As [explained on the British Council's *Learn English* site](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar/past-simple), the interrogative (questioning) form of the past simple uses ***did*** followed by the subject, with the **uninflected verb** (i.e. the bare infinitive) (much as the negative uses *do not*). Thus, to form the question you want, you end up with:

> Where **did you play**?

Using the preterite (past simple) or past participle forms of the verb in this case would be incorrect.